# How do I hide the nth element starting from the back

Tags: css

I'm trying to hide the nth div element starting from the back.
Using the :nth-last-child(n) selector only hides the last element within the div rather than the div itself.

I tried the following:
***.block:nth-last-child(1) {display:none;}***
The above did not do anything
***.block :nth-last-child(1) {display:none;}***
The above only hides the nth element within the div

```css
.block:nth-last-child(1) {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
    <button type="button">a</button>
    <button type="button">b</button>
    <button type="button">c</button>
</div>
<div class='block'>
    <button type="button">a</button>
    <button type="button">b</button>
    <button type="button">c</button>
</div>
<div class='block'>
    <button type="button">a</button>
    <button type="button">b</button>
    <button type="button">c</button>
</div>
<div class='block'>
    <button type="button">a</button>
    <button type="button">b</button>
    <button type="button">c</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.block:nth-last-child(2) {display:none;}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I just found out that if there are other elements in between the to be selected elements (.block in my example) you need to add these to the count for the nth.

Answer (score 0):

A "parent" element is needed to have a "child"

```css
.block:nth-last-child(2) {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
<div class='block'>
    <button type="button">a0</button>
    <button type="button">b0</button>
    <button type="button">c0</button>
</div>
<div class='block'>
    <button type="button">a1</button>
    <button type="button">b1</button>
    <button type="button">c1</button>
</div>
<div class='block'>
    <button type="button">a2</button>
    <button type="button">b2</button>
    <button type="button">c2</button>
</div>
<div class='block'>
    <button type="button">a3</button>
    <button type="button">b3</button>
    <button type="button">c3</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your selector was wrong, you need to specify that you wanna select the button.

Something like that:

```css
.block button:last-child {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class='block'>
    <button type="button">1a</button>
    <button type="button">1b</button>
    <button type="button">1c</button>
</div>
<div class='block'>
    <button type="button">2a</button>
    <button type="button">2b</button>
    <button type="button">2c</button>
</div>
<div class='block'>
    <button type="button">3a</button>
    <button type="button">3b</button>
    <button type="button">3c</button>
</div>
<div class='block'>
    <button type="button">4a</button>
    <button type="button">4b</button>
    <button type="button">4c</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Felix, I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I meant that I needed to hide the whole div (including it's contents) bearing the class 'block'